# why wont background-color work in html 5 using the <header> tag?

Tags: html

here is my html
for some reason the header tag isnt accepting the background color for black..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content=""/>
<meta name="description" content="" /> 


<style type="text/css">
    header {
        background:black;
    }

    nav ul li {
        float:left;
        margin-left:20px;
        display:block;
    }

    nav ul li {
        text-transform:capitalize;
        padding:5px 0px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">today's deals</a></li>
            <li><a href="recent.php">recent deals</a></li>

        </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>       
    </nav>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried

```
 background-color:black;
```

well it could be it's not supported still

this worked for me

```
   header {
        background-color:black;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

for thoose browsers that do support it
i guess why nothing wasn't displayed at first glance it's because the default behaviour isn't using it as a regular element rather then making the page more seo friendly

Comment: well it could be it's not supported still

Comment: if thats the case, that really sucks.

Comment: i found the solution. i set the header's css to  display: block; and it worked. that is weird. even though i had content in header it was supposed to show but the display made it work..

Answer (score 3):

I've got it! I know it's been a while, but I was having the same problem. You must remember to apply width and height attributes to the header or it will not work.

```
header {
background-color: black;
display: block;
width: 960px;
height: 300px;
}
```

I had the same problem, because the background only covered paragraph or other tags, not the whole area.

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-color` rather than `background`. Then add `display:block;`

```
header {
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you using to view the content?

Comment: You may need to add `display:block` to the header in order to get it to display the background color.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything attached to your clear class. Do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YNHnb/

```
<header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">today's deals</a></li>
        <li><a href="recent.php">recent deals</a></li>

    </ul>
<br clear="all">       
</nav>
</header>
```

Alternatively just add:

```
.clear{
 clear: both;
}
```

Comment: oh sorry, i had that in reset.css i removed it from this so that its clear

Comment: Well it fixes the problem for me, so make sure you are entering it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like the CSS from [HTML5 Boilerplat](http://html5boilerplate.com/)e to ensure a consistent look on the widest range of older browsers.

Though `<header>` and other elements can have styles applied in older IE version when using something like [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/), they won't have consistent CSS resets like `display: block` that you might expect.